# Recursively locate all files that have string "a" AND string "b" using grep

Tags: linux, string, recursion, grep, find

I've been using the following command to recursively search directories for a string.

```
grep -Rn "myString" *
```

I was wondering if someone would be so kind as to teach me how to search for multiple 
strings in the same file recursively. That is, I want to locate all file names that have **both**  "String1" **and** "String2."

If I could know the line number of each string within the file that contains both strings as well that would be great.

I've been trying several things without success. I want to start the search in a base directory and recursively search downward through all the subdirectories. If someone could help me with this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pipe the results of your first search to `grep` again:

```
grep -RlZ "String1" . | xargs -0 grep -l "String2"
```

This would list the files containing both `String1` and `String2`.

Getting the line numbers for the files containing both the strings wouldn't be probably very efficient since you need to know that *a priori*.  One way would be to again pipe the results to `grep`:

```
grep -RlZ "String1" . | xargs -0 grep -lZ "String2" | xargs -0 grep -En 'String1|String2'
```

Comment: Something something `grep --null | xargs -0`?

Comment: @kojiro Handling crazy filenames?

Comment: I'm always handling crazy filenames. Macs and Windows and Unicode, oh my!

Comment: +1; OSX users (I know the question is tagged 'linux', but this technique is generally useful): use  `--null` instead of the GNU shorthand `-Z`.

Answer (score 4):

You can have `find` cascade the checks for you:

```bsh
find . -type f -exec fgrep -q 'myString1' {} \; \
               -exec fgrep -q 'myString2' {} \; \
               -exec fgrep -q 'myString3' {} \; \
               -print
```

Comment: +1; didn't know that sequencing primaries implies ANDing them with short-circuiting (in other words: a given primary (`-exec`, `-print` here) in the sequence is only executed if ALL preceding ones evaluated to true). To satisfy the OP's request to also print out the line numbers, following @devnull's example, you could replace `-print` with `-exec fgrep -Hn -e "myString1" -e "myString2" -e "myString3" {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

```
grep --null -rl String1 . | xargs -0 grep --null -l String2 | xargs -0 grep -n -e String1 -e String2
```

There are a few ways to do this, but since you need files with both matching strings, you can find filenames with one match, then rescan them for the second.  The first grep finds filenames with the first pattern; the second re-scans those files for the second string.  Finally, a third grep prints out line numbers with matches.